# html pattern не работает, пишет "Пожалуйста, используйте требуемый формат"

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pattern = "\S+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+";
  //var pattern="/^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}\.)?[a-z]{2,4}$/i"
  /* var pattern="/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i";*/
  /*var pattern="/^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i";*/
  $("input[name='PROPERTY[24][0]']").attr("pattern", pattern);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="PROPERTY[24][0]" size="25" value="" required="" type="text">
```

ни один из перечисленных способов не работает.

Comment: А что Вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Может, проще использовать HTM5 "pattern"? [`<input  name="PROPERTY[24][0]" size="25" pattern="\S+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+" value="" required="" type="text" />`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqdof5or/)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а разве есть разница устанавливать атрибут в html или через js?

Comment: @Grundy: Смотря что нужно, разница, конечно, есть. А еще есть [`type="email"`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqdof5or/1/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, на самом деле нет :-) просто строку надо экранировать хорошо: https://jsfiddle.net/oeshbbak/1/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, вот кстати да! Стоит перенести это все в ответ :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Да, тут надо двойные слеши - `var pattern = "\\S+@[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+";` (еще `^` и  `$`), а в  "pattern" - одинарные работают + весь шаблон по умолчанию должен находить полное совпадение (целой строки).

Answer (score 3):

В `var pattern = "\S+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+";`  `\S` на самом деле является неверой escape-последовательностью, в которых обратный слеш удаляется и остаётся только символ после него. Т.е. шаблон получается `S+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+`.  Чтобы получить `\S`, надо удвоить обратные слеши.

Можно сделать и по-другому.

Для проверки вводимого адреса электронной почты достаточно использовать встроенный тип HTML5 `type="email"`:

```css
input:valid {
  color: navy;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input  name="PROPERTY[24][0]" size="25" value="" required="" type="email" />
  <input type="Submit" />
 </form>
```

Так как пример выше принимает значения типа `one_two@три`, можно использовать свое регулярное выражение в `pattern`:

```css
input:valid {
  color: navy;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input  name="PROPERTY[24][0]" size="25" pattern="\S+@\S+\.\S+" value="" required="" type="text" />
  <input type="Submit" />
 </form>
```

`pattern="\S+@\S+\.\S+"` означает, что вся строка должна состоять из символов, отличных от пробелов, в середине должен быть знак `@` и `.`.

Обратите внимание: шаблон, определённый в атрибуте `pattern`, по умолчанию должен находить полное совпадение строки, поэтому специальные метасимволы начала (`^`) и конца (`$`) строки не нужны. Также в этом случае не нужно удваивать обратные слеши.

Comment: @Wictor Stribizew , почему маски ^ и $ не работают. в моей задаче (вторая и третья pattern)

Comment: Где не работают? Не знаю, есть ли на русском, но вот тут смотрите по-английски - [*This implies that the regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the pattern attribute is matched against the entire value, not just any subset (somewhat as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end).*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute). Т.е. эти "маски" добавляются в шаблон атрибута HTML5 `pattern` автоматически.

Comment: Нужен `toString`, как делал koks_rs

Comment: В общем, в том коде нужны "якоря", см. https://jsfiddle.net/h5m8v88c/

Comment: То есть вывод такой, нужно `var pattern=''`(использовать одинарные кавычки)+ toString

Comment: В JS одинарные и двойные кавычки работают одинаково. Вот `\`` уже другое дело. В общем, ответы у Вас есть, выбирайте.

Comment: `var pattern ='\\S+@\\S+\.\\S+'; 
$("input[name='PROPERTY[24][0]']").attr("pattern",pattern);`

Comment: Тут у Вас точка недоэкранирована  - `var pattern ='\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+';`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
 var pattern =/\S+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+/;
```

[Ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/pktnjuc3/)

Comment: ari@inbox.ru не работает

Comment: @NNN, ну так потому что регекс кривой. Вопрос я так понял про то что сам паттерн не работает, а не про то как написать валидацию для мыла.

Comment: var pattern ='\\S+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+'; НАДО